# What is the tree hash of a specific commit hash?

Tags: git

I need a shell command-line which puts the tree hash corresponding to a specific commit hash. I know that `git cat-file commit $COMMITID | grep ^tree` can do it, but I have to filter the output of that. Is there any command which prints only the hash?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git log -1 --pretty="%T" $COMMITID
```

Answer (score 19):

```
git rev-parse $COMMITID^{tree}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `rev-parse` top-level directory for a commit with a traling colon `:`

```
git rev-parse ${COMMITID}:
```