# How can I quickly view the git tree hash of a commit in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

How can I quickly see the git tree hashes of the commits in my git history?

**Background.**
The tree hash is a hash of the directory contents at the given commit. It can printed via (see [What is the tree hash of a specific commit hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372784/what-is-the-tree-hash-of-a-specific-commit-hash)):

```
git log -1 --pretty="%T" $COMMIT
```

where `$COMMIT` is the commit hash for which you want to get the corresponding tree hash. Tree hashes are useful, for instance, in Julia (see https://arbitrary-but-fixed.net/git/julia/2021/03/18/git-tree-sha1-to-commit-sha1.html).

What I would like is a nicer way to obtain the tree hashes for the commits in my history. The question is whether vscode (or a plugin) offers some interface to view the tree hashes for all commits. I am looking for a nicer alternative than having to go, commit by commit, find the commit hash, then `git log -1 --pretty="%T" $COMMIT` with that commit hash, and so on.

Comment: Why the close vote? Please leave a comment!

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what your the question is? From the command in your question, you seem to already know how to print the tree IDs for the commits in your history.

Comment: @Brian61354270 The question is about vscode and whether it (or a plugin) offers some interface to view the tree hashes for all commits. I am looking for a nicer alternative than having to go, commit by commit, finding the commit hash, then `git log -1 --pretty="%T" $COMMIT` with that commit hash.

Comment: @a06e I can't speak for VS Code integrations, but if you drop the `-1` flag to `git log`, you'd be able to see the tree hashes for the entire history. Maybe you're looking for something like `git log --graph --all --pretty="%C(auto)%h/%t%d %s"`?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Ah thanks! Yes, that's much better than what I had. It would be nice though if this was readily available from the vscode interface, say in the Git Graph plugin or something.

Comment: An integrated terminal is much more powerful than any Git plugin if you are familiar with commands. A Git plugin usually has only basic and limited functionality.

Comment: @ElpieKay Okay but a GUI is also convenient sometimes!

Comment: the gitlens extension has a "commit graph" feature, but it looks like you can't customize columns -- just choose to show/hide predefined ones.

Comment: Yes, it is. May I ask why you want tree hashes? IMO, a tree object is not for daily use and it's not something we'd expect from a GUI. To my experience, I read and use tree hashes only in scripts.

Comment: fwiw: in a terminal, `git log --graph --format="%C(auto)%h %t %d %s"` should give you an already decent view of your commit graph, each line starting with "[commit sha] [tree sha]"

Comment: @ElpieKay See the link in the OP. Julia uses tree hashes in a few places (package manager, registry, artifacts, etc.)